# How is page loading affected by the JavaScript 'Script DOM Element' technique?

Tags: javascript, browser, javascript-injection

If I inject a script tag into a web page using the "Script DOM Element" approach like this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'http://someplace.com/a.js';
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
```

then which of the following will occur:

1 - the page will finish loading and then go back to process the inserted script tag

or

2 - the browser will pause the page load at the point the script is injected into the page, download a.js, execute it, and then continue loading the rest of the page.

And will all browsers behave the same in this regard?

Thank you.

Comment: #1 and all browsers behave the same. use document.write(<script...) to FORCE a pause like you describe in #2.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you. After I posted the question I realised it must be #1 as that is the point of the Script DOM Element technique. +1